# Merging duplicate cells and combine values in other columns

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry that I am new to VBA. I tried to search for relevant answers but failed to solve what i need. I have a list of data with many columns. Basically I want to merge the identical cells in column B, and then merge all other unique values   (from Column C to X) on the same sheet

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLcMe.jpg)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDojK.jpg)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `scripting.dictionary` to do this.

You will have to amend the ranges and sheet names to suit. Also the size of the array will need to be dealt with if you are going over 1000 rows of data.

```
Sub dave()

Dim dicKey As String
Dim dicValues As String
Dim dic
Dim data
Dim x(1 To 1000, 1 To 24)
Dim j As Long
Dim count As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     data = Range("A2:X" & lastrow) ' load data into variable
             With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
                    For i = 1 To UBound(data)
                         If .Exists(data(i, 2)) = True Then 'test to see if the key exists
                             x(count, 3) = x(count, 3) & ";" & data(i, 3)
                             x(count, 5) = x(count, 5) & ";" & data(i, 5)
                             x(count, 8) = x(count, 8) & ";" & data(i, 8)
                             x(count, 9) = x(count, 9) & ";" & data(i, 9)
                         Else
                            count = count + 1
                            dicKey = data(i, 2) 'set the key
                            dicValues = data(i, 2) 'set the value for data to be stored
                            .Add dicKey, dicValues
                            For j = 1 To 24
                              x(count, j) = data(i, j)
                            Next j
                         End If
                      Next i
              End With

              Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 1).Resize(count - 1, 9).Value = x
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! Sorry that I encountered an error after I adjust them with the respective columns. There is an error "subscript out of range" for the line  For j = 1 To 24

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, re-copy the code and try again. It should copy columns from `A:X`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works beautifully=)

Comment: Feel free to upvote the answer if it helped.